# Cannot disable localParticipant.audioTracks with Twilio Video

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-video

I'm adapting Twilio's [JS Quickstart](https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-js) and trying to provide a button that will mute a user's audio. From looking around online, my code looks like this:

```
function toggleAudio(){
  room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(track) {
    console.log(track);
    track.disable();
  })
}
```

The console.log() spits out a `LocalAudioTrackPublication`, yet I get the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: track.disable is not a function`

So I'm stumped. The docs imply that the `.disable()` method will do what I expect, yet apparently, it's not defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was such a ridiculously simple solution, as is always the case.

```
function toggleAudio(){
  room.localParticipant.audioTracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.track.disable();
  })
}
```

The actual track is inside of the track property.